# after verifying user phone number in a form, who to securely pass it for JS to PHP so I could save it in DB?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase

form of user information including name, address,,, and phone number. At the phone number, I have used js with firebase to verify it and it works fine. Now with all in the user's information, I could POST and GET in PHP fine and insert to DB.

however, the user can easily change the number after verifying it and before submitting the form! after a search I know there is a way to verify UID token on the server-side with PHP, but couldn't understand how to do it! if you know a code that i could use please help.

if there is no way, how easy is it to overtake the JS validation and submit the form?

Comment: You can validate the number right before sending to the backend. On the other hand, you may want to have another validation step in the backend.

Comment: yes, but it is JS the user can modify it and pass it, right? i mean not like PHP?